# It tells me that I exceeded the maximum number of executions when trying to publish content

Tags: posts, pages, publish

I need the code to replace a post to be executed when publishing, it asks me for the ''updateSaved'' function.

```php
function actualizacionPost($condicion){
                        
                        if($condicion == 0){
                            $args = [
                                'post_type' => array('page','post'),
                                    'numberposts' => -1,
                                ];
                            $posts = get_posts($args);

                            foreach($posts as $post){
                                $contenido_modificado = preg_replace_callback('/\[et_pb_section[^\]]*\]/i', function($matches) {
                                    $seccion = $matches[0];
                                
                                    if (preg_match('/hover_transition_duration="/i', $seccion)) {
                                        // Si existe 
                                        $seccion = preg_replace('/hover_transition_duration="[^"]*"/i', 'hover_transition_duration="0ms"', $seccion);
                                    } else {
                                        // En caso de que esté por defecto, no existe, entonces se agrega
                                        $seccion = preg_replace('/\]/', ' hover_transition_duration="0ms"]', $seccion);
                                    }
                                
                                    return $seccion;
                                }, $post->post_content);
                                
                                
                                $post = array(
                                    'ID'           => $post-> ID,
                                    'post_content' => $contenido_modificado,
                                );
                            
                                wp_update_post( $post );
                                
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            $args = [
                                'post_type' => array('page','post'),
                                    'p' => $condicion,
                                ];
                            $posts = get_posts($args);

                            $contenido_modificado = preg_replace_callback('/\[et_pb_section[^\]]*\]/i', function($matches) {
                                $seccion = $matches[0];
                            
                                if (preg_match('/hover_transition_duration="/i', $seccion)) {
                                    // Si existe 
                                    $seccion = preg_replace('/hover_transition_duration="[^"]*"/i', 'hover_transition_duration="0ms"', $seccion);
                                } else {
                                    // En caso de que esté por defecto, no existe, entonces se agrega
                                    $seccion = preg_replace('/\]/', ' hover_transition_duration="0ms"]', $seccion);
                                }
                            
                                return $seccion;
                            }, $posts);

                            $post = array(
                                'ID'           => $condicion,
                                'post_content' => $contenido_modificado,
                            );
                        
                            wp_update_post( $post );
                        }
                        
                        foreach($posts as $post){
                            $contenido_modificado = preg_replace_callback('/\[et_pb_section[^\]]*\]/i', function($matches) {
                                $seccion = $matches[0];
                            
                                if (preg_match('/hover_transition_duration="/i', $seccion)) {
                                    // Si existe 
                                    $seccion = preg_replace('/hover_transition_duration="[^"]*"/i', 'hover_transition_duration="0ms"', $seccion);
                                } else {
                                    // En caso de que esté por defecto, no existe, entonces se agrega
                                    $seccion = preg_replace('/\]/', ' hover_transition_duration="0ms"]', $seccion);
                                }
                            
                                return $seccion;
                            }, $post->post_content);
                            
                            
                            $post = array(
                                'ID'           => $post-> ID,
                                'post_content' => $contenido_modificado,
                            );
                        
                            wp_update_post( $post );
                            
                        }
                    }

                    if (false === get_transient('mi_codigo_ejecutado')) {
                        $condicion = 0;
                        actualizacionPost($condicion);
                    }
                    set_transient('mi_codigo_ejecutado', true, DAY_IN_SECONDS);

                    function actualizarGuardado(){

                        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') {
                            $url = "https://"; 
                          }else{
                            $url = "http://"; 
                          }
                        $url_actual = $url . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
                        $mypost_id = url_to_postid ($url_actual);

                        actualizacionPost($mypost_id);
                    }
                    add_action('save_post','actualizarGuardado');
```

Comment: can you edit your question to include the error message unmodified? It's not clear what the problem is, e.g. is it an issue with maximum PHP time limit? Infinite loop detection? Max Memory limit? Something else? You mention `updateSaved` too but I cannot see that function in your question. I edited the Q to fix the code block formatting but the indentation was all wrong, can you fix that? Are you using nested functions?

Comment: as a sidenote, `actualizacionPost` calls itself, and there's a call to `wp_update_post` which also triggers the `save_post` action which you're using further down and adding on every call. If you add a function 5 times it will get called 5 times when that action fires, it doesn't de-duplicate